# Need to create a salesforce trailhead leaderboard for my organization

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Need to create a salesforce trailhead leaderboard for my organization but there is no api for getting the data from the trailhead, how i can get this. is there any api key available to get data from the trialhead account?

solution for my problem